# Large latency between Europe and India on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have a video conference server in Europe hosted on Google Cloud Engine. I have users in Europe and India connecting to the same server. The server use UDP and TCP sockets.
The latency between Europe and India on Google Cloud premium network tier is three times larger compared to AWS and Azure [1][2].

The standard network tier has lower latency compared to the premium network tier. Is there a way to connect users in Europe with the premium network tier and users in India with the standard network tier to the same GCE instance?

Does Google Cloud plan to build direct connection between India and Europe and decrease the latency?

[1] https://www.cbronline.com/news/aws-vs-azure-vs-gcp

[2] https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-latency/

Comment: 1/2) There is no real hard data in your question to diagnose latency, routes, delays or substantiate your data about other providers. Please edit your question with trace routes showing the hops from the client to your conference server. Add details showing your measurements that compare GCP to AWS and Azure.

Comment: 2/2) Regarding GCP plans to build networks, Stackoverflow is not the place to ask. Google publishes its plans. For plans that are not public, you will not get official answers here. Without real data that we can analyze, your questions cannot be answered.

Comment: Two more sources: https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/gcp_inter_region_latency.html https://medium.com/@sachinkagarwal/public-cloud-inter-region-network-latency-as-heat-maps-134e22a5ff19

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's a know fact that GCP doesn't have direct route between India and Europe. My test prove it and several resources on the web suggests the same. If you think I'm wrong, please close this question. https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#network-tab

Comment: Asking for more data or reproduction steps is needed when the cause is unknown and engineers are unable to reproduce it. You can start two VMs in India and Europe and ping between them to see the relatively high latency. It takes minutes and cost cents. MTR is needed when you don't control the infrastructure and  trying to detect where is the problem. Google owns the network so MTR is irrelevant.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not work that way you want. You have asked the question, you provide the requested data. We do not need to reproduce or prove your issue. You provide the information and then we give you answers/advice/solutions based upon information in your question and from no other resources. As you stated this only costs a few cents, do so and provide the results. Read this link and follow Stackoverflow's requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

The question about network tiers only applies to the destination of the customers (the VM, or the load balancer, if one is configured). The source of the connection (customer's computers for example) does not matter. That being said, if you are connecting to the public IP of a GCE VM from your computers, the only place where network tier applies is on the GCE VM itself. As long as the VM has a premium tier network connection, anyone who connects to it (regardless of location) will be using the VM's premium tier.

In your case, since the video conference server in Europe hosted on Google Cloud Engine, India will have comparatively higher latency because of the distance. That is expected, however I would not expect it to be significantly slower. For example, if you copy of your GCE instance in APAC, you may see a reduction in latency for customers in India, not sure if that is an option for you though.

In GCP, premium Tier delivers traffic from external systems to GCP resources using Google's low latency, highly reliable global network compared to standard network tier. You may have a look at this article to get more information on the comparison between these two network tiers[1]. Different cloud providers have their infrastructure set up differently, so there can be variance concerning the route traffic will take to arrive at its destination when it comes to specific source and destination regions.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview

Comment: The latency is high not just because of the distance. The latency is 3 times higher than AWS and Azure. You can test it or check the links in the question.

Comment: Could you share MTR[1] test results run from both sources (i.e users in Europe and India) to your destination GCE VM. This will give a clear idea on the network path it is following and it’s associated network latency for each of the hop.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)

Comment: This presentation says: "Traffic moves through the GCP backbone through the United States". https://image.slidesharecdn.com/cloudwarslive-emea-v-181211133828/95/cloud-wars-performance-benchmarking-aws-gcp-and-azure-emea-version-24-638.jpg?cb=1544535673

Comment: @pablo - Source and Date of that slide, please.

Comment: This is the slideshow: https://www.slideshare.net/ThousandEyes/cloud-wars-performance-benchmarking-aws-gcp-and-azure-emea-version